# Say you boil a liquid in an airtight container, what happens once it cools?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

The title says it all, Would the liquid just return to its original form? Also if the liquid is not water, would you still loose some volume due to saturation?

Answer (score 1):

If the airtight container withstands the pressure during heating upon the water will return to its original state upon cooling. You will not lose any volume for any liquid that doesn't undergo an irrevesible phase change.

Answer (score 0):

Mass of substance inside does not change because container is airtight. If initial and final temperature and total volume of the container are the same, then you have returned to the same thermodynamic state with which you began. It does not matter what substance is present inside.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sealed container at constant temperature which has water (liquid) and water (vapour) then an equilibrium stae will be set up when the number of molecules per second leaving the liquid and going into the vapour phase  will equal the number of molecules per second leaving the vapour and going into the liquid phase.
There is a dynamic equilibrium set up the the vapour pressure reaches a constant value, the saturated vapour pressure.
The saturated vapour pressure only depends on the temperature.

Raising the temperature of the container will produce a net transfer of liquid into vapour until again a dynamic equilibrium is set up with a higher saturated vapour pressure.

If now you cool the container the process is reverse and there is a net transfer of vapour into liquid and this continues until a new lower saturated vapour pressure is set up.

So when you started the experiment and the temperature of the water was $100^\circ {\rm C}$ the vapour pressure would increase and so would the boiling point of the water until a dynamic equilibrium was reached at say $103^\circ {\rm C}$ when the saturated vapour pressure would be higher as there had been a net transfer of liquid to vapour.
Reducing the temperature down to $100^\circ {\rm C}$ would result in a net transfer of vapour to liquid until the original state at $100^\circ {\rm C}$ was reached with the same proportions of liquid and vapour.

Comment: So by changing temperature in closed container is like affecting the pressure so boiling point rises? Does this hold only for small containers? I mean if we consider a room as a vessel then the liquid does not exist in equilibrium with the vapour at high temperature (all liquid turns into gas). Is this because the pressure above the liquid effectively stays the same (e.g. 1 atm)?

Comment: Can you completely seal a room?  The bigger the volume the harder it is to make it a closed system.

Comment: I just suppose that the volume of the vessel is too large. In that case all liquid turns into vapor but it doesn't condense back to liquid (no equilibrium between vapor and liquid). Can this be explained by the fact that the pressure after the vaporization (which for a system composed only of water vapor will be the pressure of the vapor and for a very large vessel the pressure will be very small? Therefore, the vapor don't condensate, even though is at room temperature (heat exchange with surroundings), because the boiling point is lower for lower pressure.